# Can Powershell Merge Inherited and Non-Inherited ACLs easily to set effective permissions on a new copy location?

Tags: powershell, acl

I want to copy files in Windows from location A to location B maintaining the permissions using PowerShell.

The origin directory has permissions applied to it directly, and inherits some from parent folders. Example:

| Principal | Access | Inherited From | Applies to |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| User1 | List folder contents |  | This folder and subfolders |
| User1 | Read |  | *This folder, subfolders and files* |
| User1 | List folder contents | \server\parentfolder\ | This folder and subfolders |
| User1 | Read | \server\parentfolder\ | *Subfolders and files only* |

Effectively, User1 has the following rights on the origin folder:

- List folder contents - This folder and subfolders
- Read - This folder, subfolders and files

On the destination folder the user ends up with:

- List folder contents - This folder and subfolders
- Read - Subfolders and files only

The 4th set of rights applied are inherited on the origin, and overwrites the explicit permission (#2) on the destination.

Doing a straight Get-ACL / Set-ACL will copy both inherited and direct ACEs, but the destination folder only keeps one set - the most recent ACLs applied.

Robocopy with /sec and DATSO were the first things we tried. It had an attribute error on a specific attribute that with a powershell script I think we can log and just re-apply manually on the destination.

I think I'll have to make the script read in each ACE, determine the effective permissions each principal should have, and then apply them - but it feels like I'm re-inventing the wheel. My first attempt was just changing the order to set the inherited permissions first, but unless there's a better option I think I'll need to make some kind of multi-dimensional hashtable to track and rebuild merged destination ACLs:

```
 param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$RootOrigin, # copy from location
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$RootDestination # to location
 )


function copy-with-acls {
    param (
        [String]$FullPath,
        [String]$DestinationRoot,
        [String]$DirectoryOrFile
    )
    
    # Create an array of paths to migrate ACLs for
    $Paths = @() 
    Write-Host "FullPath: $($FullPath)"
    Write-Host "DestinationRoot: $($DestinationRoot)"
    Write-Host "DirectoryOrFile $($DirectoryOrFile)"
    If ($DirectoryOrFile -eq "Directory") {
        Write-Host "Collecting Directory paths"
        $Paths +=  @((Get-Item -Path $FullPath).FullName)
        $Paths += Get-ChildItem -Path $FullPath -Recurse -Directory | ForEach-Object {$_.FullName}
    } Else {  
        Write-Host "Collecting File paths"
        $Paths += Get-ChildItem -Path $FullPath -Recurse -File | ForEach-Object {$_.FullName}
    }

    # for each path Copy file, Gather ACL
    Write-Host "Copying $($Paths.Count) $($DirectoryOrFile)s"
    ForEach ($Path in $Paths) {
        # Copy file or folder
        # Write-Host "Copying: $($Path) To: $($Destination)"
        $Destination = $Path.Replace($FullPath,$DestinationRoot)
        
        If ($DirectoryOrFile -eq "Directory") {
            robocopy $Path $Destination *.__1234___ /j /copy:DAT /dcopy:DAT /R:30 /W:60 # This robocopy is effectively just copying the folder with attributes/times. Probably a better way to do this.
        } Else {
            $FileName = Split-Path $Destination -Leaf
            $FilePath = Split-Path $Destination -Parent
            robocopy $Path $FilePath $FileName /j /copy:DAT /dcopy:DAT /R:30 /W:60 # This robocopy will only copy the file in the Path
        }
    }
    
    ForEach ($Path in $Paths) {    
        # Get ACLs
        $OriginAcl = Get-Acl -Path $Path        
        $Destination = $Path.Replace($FullPath,$DestinationRoot)
        $DestinationAcl = Get-Acl -Path $Destination

        # Get and Set ACLs which match the functions filter parameters
        # Do inherited ACLs first
        ForEach ($Access in $PathAcl.Access | where {($_.isinherited) -and ($_.identityreference -notin $excludepattern)}) {
            Write-Host "Principal: $($Access.identityreference), Inherited?: $($Access.isinherited)"
            $DestinationAcl.AddAccessRule($Access)
            Write-Host "Applied Inherited true"
        }

        # Get and Set ACLs which match the functions filter paramenters 
        # Next do directly applied ACLs
        ForEach ($Access in $PathAcl.Access | where {(-not $_.isinherited) -and ($_.identityreference -notin $excludepattern)}) {
            Write-Host "Principal: $($Access.identityreference), Inherited?: $($Access.isinherited)"
            $DestinationAcl.AddAccessRule($Access)
            Write-Host "Applied Inherited false"
        }
        Set-Acl -Path $Destination -AclObject $DestinationAcl
    }
    
}

# Copy directories first so that permissions don't need to be updated on individual files
copy-with-acls $RootOrigin $RootDestination "Directory"
copy-with-acls $RootOrigin $RootDestination "File"
```